# htaccess adding [NC,F] to GET parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on an MVC project and I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^(public/|index\.php) [NC,F]
```

It works OK. I only want the `public/` folder and the `index.php` file to be accessible to the public. All other paths should be inserted into the `path` GET parameter. For example, `mysite.com/controller/method` should point to `mysite.com/index.php?path=controller/method`.

Now, there is a problem. When visiting the URL directly (without including `index.php`, it is adding `[NC,F]` to the GET `path` parameter. It's like visiting `mysite.com` is pointing to `mysite.com/index.php?path=[NC,F]`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

I moved `index.php` into the `public/` folder. Here is my `.htaccess` file now:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule !^(public/) [NC,F]
```

It seems to work OK. Are there any other improvements I could make on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a redirect location on the last rule, so it's taking the flags as the redirect location. Just a dash will be fine since it's a forbidden response. Change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule !^(public/|index\.php$) - [NC,F]
```

Also adding the dollar sign after index.php just to be clear.

**Edit:**

I would suggest updating your new rule set to the following (actually I suggest a complete re-think below, but this is an update on what you have):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^(public/) - [NC,F]
```

The `(/)?` wasn't needed in your homepage rule, as the opening forward slash is not included in `.htaccess` matches anyway.

I moved your rule for the homepage to the top or it will never be used due to being matched by the previous rule (so the path param is not there when empty, which is presumably what you intended).

I stopped anything in /public/ from being passed to your index.php script, since the way you had it, anything in public that didn't exist would have been passed to your index script, which does not seem to be what you intend.

I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/public/index.php` so the rule couldn't be executed on itself and create a loop if rule processing is run through more than once, which it can be, but then took it back out because the above match on /public/ covers that anyway.

**A Re-Think**

All that said, I don't think it really makes sense to check if files don't exist and then just send forbidden responses to the ones that do, yet send everything else to your index script. Why not just send everything to your index script? That seems to be what you want really. I would suggest you simplify to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Dropping the homepage rule since no need to worry about an empty path parameter being passed to your index script. Changing the logic to be "Leave anything in /public/ alone. For anything else, pass it through to the index.php script." so files tests not needed since the script handles it all, and no forbidden response needed because there is nothing left to match, it's all covered by the rules. You can always return forbidden to anything you don't want to process in your script, which you would have needed to do anyway for existing file URLs in your previous setup.

**One Last Re-Think**

And finally, if I might suggest, it would be cleaner to have your index.php file in the root of the website, so you can make /public/ work with its own index file later if you like, so finally I would move it back to the root and change the rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

And if you like all that, an up-vote to go with already accepting the answer would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]` seems to have resolved the issue. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but here is my `.htaccess` file now:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule !^(public/) [NC,F]
```

I moved `index.php` into the public folder to make things clearer.

Comment: You still have the problem that is identified in my answer.  It's a simple fix, but there are a couple of other potential issues that need resolving too. Difficult to answer now that your answer has changed the code from the question. Really your question needs updating.

Comment: I implemented the dash you mentioned. What other issues do you see? Keep in mind I moved the `index.php` file into the `public/` folder.

Comment: Well the L doesn't mean it's not going to get run again, it just stops than round of rules, so you need to check that the URL isn't already index.php in your first rewriterule. .htaccess rewrite sets can get run multiple times through.

Comment: Also please accept my answer as it answered the problem in your question.

Comment: So how would you structure the `.htaccess` file? It seems to be working OK now, but my knowledge of `htaccess` if very limited and I know I'm probably missing a bunch of stuff.

Comment: If you update your question with an edit, adding your updated rule set, I will update my answer addressing those issues and giving you the rules as I suggest they should be.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the OP as you requested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did that last rule set I suggested work for you? If there's some caveat of your setup that I missed in my assumptions let me know and I'd be happy to tweak it.